# Is it possible to create a docker-compose.yml file which uses another one and modifies some settings in it?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

We have a project which uses `docker-compose.yml` file to run several services. Our developers use that to run and test the software on their local dockers.
However, when running this on our server, I need to have some changes: we have a docker network setup + some env variables which have to be set.
Normally, we would have to create a copy of the file and apply those changes there. This will mean that when a dev makes changes to the regular docker-compose.yml file, he will have to remember that there's another file to be changed. This never works. I know we could make a git hook to monitor for changes in this file and ask for similar in the other file, but I can see possibilities of changes which may not have to be reflected in the other one.

I wanted to know if there's a way to create a separate docker compose file, which will take the original one and add some changes to it?

Thanks
Krystian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, docker-compose [support inheritance](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/).

Compose supports two methods of sharing common configuration:

- Extending an entire Compose file by using multiple Compose files
- Compose supports two methods of sharing common configuration:

Comment: damn I didn't see it before. Thanks a lot!